# ExecutorService with Java Streams gives this error " java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException"

Tags: java, optimization, java-stream, executorservice, java.util.concurrent

I have code that needs finds the N-number of optimal combinations taking exactly 1 "player" from 8 ArrayLists of "players". Each ArrayList is anywhere from 20 - 40. Which results in a huge run times with that many iterations. Before attempting to optimize run time, the code was fully functioning, just with undesirable run time. I decided the best way to do this was the use of Executor Services and Java Streams, despite me being new to both. This is a minimized version of my code below:

```
public static void main(String [] args){
//Lineup is an object which I store the combination of players in
ArrayList <Lineup> currBoard = new ArrayList<Lineup>();
final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nThreads);
    String threadId = Thread.currentThread().getName();
    int tid = Integer.parseInt(threadId.substring(threadId.length() - 1));
    int threadWorkLoad = newPG.size() / 4;
    //int threadStart = (int)(tid - 1) * threadWorkLoad;
    final List<Future<?>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
    System.out.println(newPG.size());
    for(int i=0; i < nThreads; i++){        
        Future<?> future = executorService.submit(() -> {
                    //System.out.println(pg.getName());
                    
                    currBoard.addAll(parallelFunction(nThreads, amounts, newPG, newSG, newSF, newPF, newC, newG, newF, newL));
                    
                
                
        });
        futures.add(future);
    }
    executorService.shutdown();
    try{
        executorService.awaitTermination(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }catch(InterruptedException e){
        System.out.println("oof");
    }
    try {
        for (Future<?> future : futures) {
            future.get(); // do anything you need, e.g. isDone(), ...
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And here is the function which I iterate through the possible lineups

```
public ArrayList<Lineup> parallelFunction(int nThreads, int amounts, ArrayList<Player> newPG, ArrayList<Player> newSG, ArrayList<Player> newSF,
    ArrayList<Player> newPF, ArrayList<Player> newC, ArrayList<Player> newG, ArrayList<Player> newF,
        ArrayList<Player> newL) {

    ArrayList<Player> temp = new ArrayList<Player>();
    
    ArrayList<Lineup> threadBoard = new ArrayList<Lineup>();

    String threadId = Thread.currentThread().getName();
    int tid = Integer.parseInt(threadId.substring(threadId.length() - 1));
    int threadWorkLoad = (newPG.size() + nThreads - 1) / nThreads;
    int threadStart = (int)(tid - 1) * threadWorkLoad;
    int threadStop = Math.min(threadStart + threadWorkLoad, newPG.size());
    //ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    
    
    ArrayList<Player> tempPG = new ArrayList<Player>();

    for(int i = threadStart; i <= threadStop; i++){
        tempPG.add(newPG.get(i));
    }

    Stream<Player> pgStream = StreamSupport.stream(tempPG.spliterator(), true);
    pgStream.forEach(pg -> {

        System.out.println("TID: " + tid + ", PG: " + pg.getName() + ", iterations: " + counting);
        Stream<Player> sgStream = StreamSupport.stream(newSG.spliterator(), true);
        sgStream.forEach(sg -> {
        //System.out.println(tid + ", " + sg.getName());
        Stream<Player> sfStream = StreamSupport.stream(newSF.spliterator(), true);
        sfStream.forEach(sf -> {
            Stream<Player> pfStream = StreamSupport.stream(newPF.spliterator(), true);
            pfStream.forEach(pf -> {
                Stream<Player> cStream = StreamSupport.stream(newC.spliterator(), true);
                cStream.forEach(c -> {
                    Stream<Player> gStream = StreamSupport.stream(newG.spliterator(), true);
                    gStream.forEach(g -> {
                        if ((!(g.getName().equals(sg.getName()) || g.getName().equals(pg.getName())))
                                && ((pg.getSalary() + sg.getSalary() + sf.getSalary() + pf.getSalary()
                                        + c.getSalary() + 3000 + 3000 + 3000) < 50000)) {
                                Stream<Player> fStream = StreamSupport.stream(newF.spliterator(), true);
                                fStream.forEach(f -> {
                                if ((!(f.getName().equals(sf.getName()) || f.getName().equals(pf.getName())))
                                        && ((g.getSalary() + pg.getSalary() + sg.getSalary() + sf.getSalary()
                                                + pf.getSalary() + c.getSalary() + 3000 + 3000) < 50000)) {
                                        Stream<Player> pStream = StreamSupport.stream(newL.spliterator(), true);
                                        pStream.forEach(p -> {
                                        if (!(p.getName().equals(pg.getName()) || p.getName().equals(sg.getName())
                                                || p.getName().equals(sf.getName())
                                                || p.getName().equals(pf.getName())
                                                || p.getName().equals(c.getName())
                                                || p.getName().equals(g.getName())
                                                || p.getName().equals(f.getName()))) {
                                            double currScore = 0;
                                            double totalSal = 0;
                                            totalSal = pg.getSalary() + sg.getSalary() + sf.getSalary()
                                                    + pf.getSalary() + c.getSalary() + f.getSalary() + g.getSalary()
                                                    + p.getSalary();
                                            currScore = pg.getProjection() + sg.getProjection() + sf.getProjection()
                                                    + pf.getProjection() + c.getProjection() + f.getProjection()
                                                    + g.getProjection() + p.getProjection();
                                            if (totalSal <= 50000.0) {
                                                counting += 1;
                                                temp.clear();
                                                temp.add(pg);
                                                temp.add(sg);
                                                temp.add(sf);
                                                temp.add(pf);
                                                temp.add(c);
                                                temp.add(g);
                                                temp.add(f);
                                                temp.add(p);
                                                ArrayList<Lineup> tempBoard = new ArrayList<Lineup>();

                                                Lineup aLine = new Lineup(temp, currScore);
                                                
                                                if (threadBoard.size() < amounts) {
                                                    if (!alreadyIn(threadBoard, temp)) {
                                                        
                                                        threadBoard.add(aLine);
                                                    }


                                                } else if (currScore > threadBoard.get(amounts - 1).totalScore) {
                                                    // Collections.sort(currBoard, Lineup.TotComp);
                                                    if (!alreadyIn(threadBoard, temp)) {
                                                        for (int i = 0; i < threadBoard.size() - 1; i++) {
                                                            tempBoard.add(threadBoard.get(i));
                                                        }
                                                        threadBoard.clear();
                                                        threadBoard.addAll(tempBoard);
                                                        tempBoard.clear();
                                                        threadBoard.add(aLine);
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                Collections.sort(threadBoard, Lineup.TotComp);
                                            }

                                            // temp.clear();
                                        } // p if
                                    });
                                    pStream.close();
                                } // f if
                            });
                            fStream.close();
                        } // g if
                    });
                    gStream.close();
                });
                cStream.close();
            });
            pfStream.close();
        });
        sfStream.close();
    });
    sgStream.close();
});
pgStream.close();







return threadBoard;
}
```

This causes this error after a decent amount of iterations, java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Is there anything that I did wrong with the executorService or streams to cause this.

Or does anyone have any suggestions to improve the speed of this code, as it still unsatisfactory with speed until it crashes.

---

### Edit

main:

```
ArrayList<Lineup> currBoard = new ArrayList<Lineup>();
    int nThreads = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();

    final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nThreads);
    String threadId = Thread.currentThread().getName();
    int tid = Integer.parseInt(threadId.substring(threadId.length() - 1));
    int threadWorkLoad = newPG.size() / 4;
    //int threadStart = (int)(tid - 1) * threadWorkLoad;
    final List<Future<ThreadBoard>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<ThreadBoard>>();
    
    for(int i=0; i < nThreads; i++){
        Future<ThreadBoard> future = executorService.submit(() -> {
                    //System.out.println(pg.getName());
                return parallelFunction(nThreads, amounts, newPG, newSG, newSF, newPF, newC, newG, newF, newL); 
        });
        futures.add(future);
    }
    executorService.shutdown();
    try{
        executorService.awaitTermination(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }catch(InterruptedException e){
        System.out.println("oof");
    }
    try {
        for (Future<ThreadBoard> future : futures) {
            currBoard.addAll(future.get().getCurrentLineup()); // do anything you need, e.g. isDone(), ...
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

parallelFunction:

```
public ThreadBoard parallelFunction(int nThreads, int amounts, ArrayList<Player> newPG, ArrayList<Player> newSG, ArrayList<Player> newSF,
    ArrayList<Player> newPF, ArrayList<Player> newC, ArrayList<Player> newG, ArrayList<Player> newF,
        ArrayList<Player> newL) {

    
    ThreadBoard threadBoard = new ThreadBoard();

    String threadId = Thread.currentThread().getName();
    int tid = Integer.parseInt(threadId.substring(threadId.length() - 1));
    int threadWorkLoad = (newPG.size() + nThreads - 1) / nThreads;
    int threadStart = (int)(tid - 1) * threadWorkLoad;
    int threadStop = Math.min(threadStart + threadWorkLoad, newPG.size());
    //ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    
    
    
    ArrayList<Player> tempPG = new ArrayList<Player>();

    for(int i = threadStart; i <= threadStop; i++){
        tempPG.add(newPG.get(i));
    }

    Stream<Player> pgStream = StreamSupport.stream(tempPG.spliterator(), false);
    pgStream.forEach(pg -> {

        System.out.println("TID: " + tid + ", PG: " + pg.getName() + ", iterations: " + counting);
        Stream<Player> sgStream = StreamSupport.stream(newSG.spliterator(), false);
        sgStream.forEach(sg -> {
        //System.out.println(tid + ", " + sg.getName());
        Stream<Player> sfStream = StreamSupport.stream(newSF.spliterator(), false);
        sfStream.forEach(sf -> {
            Stream<Player> pfStream = StreamSupport.stream(newPF.spliterator(), false);
            pfStream.forEach(pf -> {
                Stream<Player> cStream = StreamSupport.stream(newC.spliterator(), false);
                cStream.forEach(c -> {
                    Stream<Player> gStream = StreamSupport.stream(newG.spliterator(), false);
                    gStream.forEach(g -> {
                        if ((!(g.getName().equals(sg.getName()) || g.getName().equals(pg.getName())))
                                && ((pg.getSalary() + sg.getSalary() + sf.getSalary() + pf.getSalary()
                                        + c.getSalary() + 3000 + 3000 + 3000) < 50000)) {
                                Stream<Player> fStream = StreamSupport.stream(newF.spliterator(), false);
                                fStream.forEach(f -> {
                                if ((!(f.getName().equals(sf.getName()) || f.getName().equals(pf.getName())))
                                        && ((g.getSalary() + pg.getSalary() + sg.getSalary() + sf.getSalary()
                                                + pf.getSalary() + c.getSalary() + 3000 + 3000) < 50000)) {
                                        Stream<Player> pStream = StreamSupport.stream(newL.spliterator(), false);
                                        pStream.forEach(p -> {
                                        if (!(p.getName().equals(pg.getName()) || p.getName().equals(sg.getName())
                                                || p.getName().equals(sf.getName())
                                                || p.getName().equals(pf.getName())
                                                || p.getName().equals(c.getName())
                                                || p.getName().equals(g.getName())
                                                || p.getName().equals(f.getName()))) {
                                            double currScore = 0;
                                            double totalSal = 0;
                                            totalSal = pg.getSalary() + sg.getSalary() + sf.getSalary()
                                                    + pf.getSalary() + c.getSalary() + f.getSalary() + g.getSalary()
                                                    + p.getSalary();
                                            currScore = pg.getProjection() + sg.getProjection() + sf.getProjection()
                                                    + pf.getProjection() + c.getProjection() + f.getProjection()
                                                    + g.getProjection() + p.getProjection();
                                            if (totalSal <= 50000.0) {
                                                counting += 1;
                                                ArrayList<Player> temp = new ArrayList<Player>();
                                                temp.clear();
                                                temp.add(pg);
                                                temp.add(sg);
                                                temp.add(sf);
                                                temp.add(pf);
                                                temp.add(c);
                                                temp.add(g);
                                                temp.add(f);
                                                temp.add(p);

                                                Lineup aLine = new Lineup(temp, currScore);
                                                threadBoard.addLineup(aLine, currScore, amounts, temp);
                                                
                                                // if (threadBoard.size() < amounts) {
                                                //  //if (!alreadyIn(threadBoard, temp)) {
                                                        
                                                //      threadBoard.add(aLine);
                                                //  //}


                                                // } else if (currScore > threadBoard.get(amounts - 1).totalScore) {
                                                //  // Collections.sort(currBoard, Lineup.TotComp);
                                                //  //if (!alreadyIn(threadBoard, temp)) {
                                                //      for (int i = 0; i < threadBoard.size() - 1; i++) {
                                                //          tempBoard.add(threadBoard.get(i));
                                                //      }
                                                //      threadBoard.clear();
                                                //      threadBoard.addAll(tempBoard);
                                                //      tempBoard.clear();
                                                //      threadBoard.add(aLine);
                                                //  //}
                                                // }
                                                //Collections.sort(threadBoard.getCurrentLineup(), Lineup.TotComp);
                                            }

                                            //temp.clear();
                                        } // p if
                                    });
                                    pStream.close();
                                } // f if
                            });
                            fStream.close();
                        } // g if
                    });
                    gStream.close();
                });
                cStream.close();
            });
            pfStream.close();
        });
        sfStream.close();
    });
    sgStream.close();
});
pgStream.close();







return threadBoard;
}
```

ThreadBoard class:

```
public class ThreadBoard {
private List<Lineup> lineups;

public ThreadBoard(){
    this.lineups = new ArrayList<>();
}

public synchronized void addLineup(Lineup aLine, double currScore, int amounts, ArrayList<Player> temp) {
    if (lineups.size() < amounts) {
        if (!this.alreadyIn(lineups, temp)) {
            lineups.add(aLine);
        }
    } else if (currScore > lineups.get(amounts - 1).totalScore) {
        // Collections.sort(currBoard, Lineup.TotComp);
        if (!this.alreadyIn(lineups, temp)) {
            lineups.set(amounts - 1, aLine);
        }
    }
    Collections.sort(lineups, Lineup.TotComp);
}

public List<Lineup> getCurrentLineup() {
    return lineups;
}

public boolean alreadyIn(List<Lineup> board, ArrayList<Player> temp) {
    boolean found = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < board.size(); i++) {
        
        ArrayList <Player> check = board.get(i).getL();

        boolean pg = (check.contains(temp.get(0)));
        boolean sg = (check.contains(temp.get(1)));
        boolean pf = (check.contains(temp.get(2)));
        boolean sf = (check.contains(temp.get(3)));
        boolean c = (check.contains(temp.get(4)));
        boolean g = (check.contains(temp.get(5)));
        boolean f = (check.contains(temp.get(6)));
        boolean all = (check.contains(temp.get(7)));

        if (pg && sg && pf && sf && c && g && f && all) {
            found = true;
        }
    }
    

    return found;
}
```

}

Comment: You can't consume a `Stream` more than once. According to the [Package java.util.stream Description](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html): _Consumable. The elements of a stream are only visited once during the life of a stream. Like an Iterator, a new stream must be generated to revisit the same elements of the source._

Comment: @ThomasKläger I moved the Stream declarations to right before each call and it did indeed remove the error. I had the declarations there before not entirely sure as to why I moved them

Comment: @ThomasKläger however I did make an edit to describe the other issue the code is having

Comment: Sorry, but your code is to complicated for me to understand it. But as far as I noticed you are using parallel streams to process the data, which means that `ArrayList<Player> temp` and `ArrayList<Lineup> threadBoard` from `parallelFunction()` as well as `ArrayList <Lineup> currBoard` from the main method will make problems because a simple `ArrayList` is not a thread safe data structure, but you are accessing these ArrayLists from multiple threads.

Comment: @ThomasKläger thank you for the input, to your knowledge would creating duplicates of the ArrayLists in the parallelFunction() help at all or would the same problem of thread safety arise?

Comment: For the `ArrayList<Player> temp` the solution is to put it into the innermost lambda where it is effectively used. Then it is no longer shared and the problems with that ArrayList are solved. For the `ArrayList<Lineup> currBoard` (in main) the solution is to let the jobs that you submit return `ArrayList<Lineup>`. Then you can collect the results of all jobs in the main thread from the `Future<ArrayList<Lineup>>`s and the threading issues with that ArrayList are also solved.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the `ArrayList<Lineup> threadBoard` is that it is used to collect, sort and limit the results from different parallel streams. IMHO an ArrayList is not the correct data structure for these tasks. I would create a separate class that does these steps:

```
public class ThreadBoard {
    private List<Lineup> currentLineup = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public void addLineup(Lineup aLine, double currScore) {
        if (currentLineup.size() < amounts) {
            if (!alreadyIn(currentLineup, temp)) {
                currentLineup.add(aLine);
            }
        } else if (currScore > currentLineup.get(amounts - 1).totalScore) {
            // Collections.sort(currBoard, Lineup.TotComp);
            if (!alreadyIn(currentLineup, temp)) {
                currentLineup.set(amounts - 1, aLine);
                Collections.sort(currentLineup, Lineup.TotComp);
        }
    }

    public List<Lineup> getCurrentLineup() {
        return currentLineup;
    }
}
```

To make this thread safe you can declare the `addLineup()` method as synchronized.

However I'm not sure if all those parallel streams help the performance (since you already split the complete job into chunks that are processed in parallel).

Maybe it would make more sense to split the complete job into more, smaller chunks and then use only sequential streams to process a chunk. In the end your computer has only a limited amount of cores (maybe 4, maybe 16) and splitting a CPU bound job into many more parts (and by using nested parallel streams you are doing that) than there are cores doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Thank you so much for the continued help, however the code I changed appears to deadlock/ just not run. There is no error that appears. Is there something I did incorrectly with your suggestions? I added updated code to the post under edit.